# Concatenate columns while maintaining rows

Tags: python, numpy, concatenation

I have a numpy array that I would like to concatenate the columns into a single value for the row. Below is what I have tried so far.

```
import numpy as np

randoma=np.random.choice(list('ACTG'),(5,21),replace=True)# create a 7x21 raqndom matrix with A,C,T,G
randoma=np.concatenate(randoma, axis=None)
```

expected results is something like

```
randoma = ['AAGCCGCACACAGACCCTGAG',
    'AAGCTGCACGCAGACCCTGAG',
    'AGGCTGCACGCAGACCCTGAG',
    'AAGCTGCACGTGGACCCTGAG',
    'AGGCTGCACGTGGACCCTGAG',
    'AGGCTGCACGTGGACCCTGAG',
    'AAGCTGCATGTGGACCCTGAG']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
randoma = np.random.choice(list('ACTG'),(5,21),replace=True)  # create a 7x21 raqndom matrix with A,C,T,G

new_list = [''.join(x) for x in randoma.tolist()]
new_list
['CGGGACGCACTTCCTGTGCAG',
 'TGTAGCGGCTTGGTGTCCAAG',
 'GAAAGTTTAGGATTGCGTCGG',
 'AGTATTGTGATTCTATCTGAC',
 'TTAGTAAGAGTGTCTCACTAT']
```